# How to get part of a text contents from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have a string like

```
I Love you and you love me [end] a lot of people hate us
```

How could I write a T-SQL `SELECT` statement in which I could get the part

```
I Love you and you love me
```

only? Everything after `[end]` should be ignored.

Comment: Pick one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) functions. Substring maybe? Or left? In combi with Charindex?

Comment: @Rene - thanks. The difficult is it is not a fixed-length string.

Comment: That can be solved with charindex, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this tsql statement only uses [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
 DECLARE @str nvarchar(250)
   SELECT @str = 'I Love you and you love me [end] a lot of people hate us'

   SELECT LEFT(@str, 
          case when CHARINDEX('[end]',@str)>0 
               then CHARINDEX('[end]',@str)-1 
           else LEN(@str) end) -- use 0 if you want an empty string to be returned
```

Comment: Thank for the error handling. Just one extend to the question, IF there is not [END] found, I would like it return the whole text instead of 0. How should I do it?  I tried SELECT @str instead of 0 but nah, it does not work

Comment: I know return the whole string